# I m not getting proper balanced days from below code:

Tags: php

```
$b='2014-06-01 14:57:15';
echo "Future Date:".$b;
$a=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo "Current Date:".$a;
$c=$b-$a;
echo "Balance:".$c;
/*Its displaying one but want 6 months in answer*/
$d=date('Y-m-d H:i:s')+$d;
echo "New Future Date:".$d;
/*Wants to add with current date so that i get new date*/
```

Comment: Hint: use `strtotime()` before substracting.

Comment: `date` returns string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 $b='2014-06-01 14:57:15';
    echo "Future Date:".$b;
    $a=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    echo "Current Date:".$a;
    $c=strtotime($b)-strtotime($a);
    echo "Balance:".$c;

   d=date('Y-m-d H:i:s' time()+$d);
   echo "New Future Date:".$d;
```